# How to use curly brackets as part of an output of a command?

Tags: macros

There's an exercise that I am clearly intended to do on paper, but for some reason I insist on doing it in LaTeX. It takes a while, though, and as such I would like to make one or more commands to abbreviate some things. In general I think this would be useful to be able to do.

 I get stuck quickly, though. I have in a tikzpicture environment the following:
`\node (square) {\textit{square}} ;`, which produces the desired result. When I then create a command `\newcommand{\testa}[1]{ \textit{#1} }`  and use `\node (square) {\testa{square}} ;`, it still works. When I create a command `\newcommand{\testb}[1]{ { \textit{#1} } }`  and use `\node (square) \testb{square} ;` however, I get "Package tikz Error: A node must have a (possibly empty) label text.". 
How can this be, and can I fix it? If so, how?
 Thanks. :) If I know how to fix this, I can expand the command so that `\node \testc{square}` will produce the desired result.

Comment: Not easily possible. `\node` looks ahead for a literal `{`.  In principle it could expand macros looking for `{` but that would require patching TikZ.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thanks. That is disappointing; I assumed commands were expanded before further compiling was done. I guess I have to learn another macro language that allows it, then... but probably not now. :P

Comment: Well, TeX allows this, it is just not implemented in TikZ.

Comment: why that syntax? You could do `\newcommand\test[1]{\node(square){#1}}`  then `\test{square}` which is shorter to use as you don't need to type `\node` every time and works without expansion issues.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Because for most nodes I will need to include location information. But as I formulate that reply I realise that I could probably include a second, optional, argument for that. That is a good idea for fixing this issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a little bit of expansion trickery but that is probably not what you are looking for because it is even more verbose than writing it out explicitly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\testb}[1]{{\textit{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \expanded{\noexpand\node (square) \unexpanded\expandafter{\testb{square}};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also give this poorly tested patch to the internal TikZ code a shot.  It introduces quite a lot of overhead in the expansion chain and produces errors that are difficult to make sense of and possibly hard to recover.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\let\tikz@@scan@fig@normal\tikz@@scan@fig
\def\tikz@@scan@fig{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\space
    {\errmessage{Can't happen!}}%
    {\expandafter\tikz@@scan@fig@normal\romannumeral-`0}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\testb}[1]{ {\textit{#1}} }
\newcommand{\testc}[1]{ (#1) {\textit{#1}} }

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (square) \testb{square};

  \node[draw] at (2,0) \testc{rectangle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```